# Keeping a 12 V circuit live briefly

Tags: led, batteries, capacitor

I have a sequential (flowing) LED vehicle indicator unit that I need to keep powered for about one second after the input is switched off.

It is intermittently powered from the vehicle's indicator circuit at about half a second on and half a second off, however, although the indicator unit has a power "reservoir" on board it doesn't support the LED's for quite long enough and the sequence is interrupted and restarted which is not the required effect.

I would guess the unit consumes a couple of watts, possibly up to five - my meter doesn't seem to work like it used to so I can't be accurate - and the voltage is a normal 12 V vehicle range.

I don't know too much about electronics, I'm better on electrics and I believe I can do the job with a capacitor, but having web-searched I can't find anything that gives me an answer to what I'll need for the sort of power and voltage I'm using.

Can someone out there suggest a value and type that will get me somewhere near to what I need?

Many thanks.

Comment: To clarify: your indicator is a standard 50% duty cycle flasher and you want the output to stay on to power your sequencer continuously as long as the indicator switch is on? How does your sequencer work?

Comment: As I said I'm electrics and not electronics - I have three wires into it, black is earth and there's a yellow wire that goes to the indicator feed and a red 12v feed that was supposed to power the white component LEDs (LEDs removed now as i's a rear facing unit).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I can't figure out what you are describing. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: If 12v is held on red and black the unit will sequence if the yellow is made live briefly and will give a partial sequence if the yellow power is interrupted, and restart if re-energised. If red and yellow are energised together the unit will run as long as both are powered, this is the part I wish to keep alive longer

Comment: You would probably be better off using a relay to get power from somewhere else, and then the capacitor only needs to keep the relay on, so it can be a lot smaller.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the replies so far. Tony's would be great if I understood more than bits of it (sorry, I'm a simple bod) but as least I have a ballpark value to start with. Immibis - Sounds like a good plan, I'll have to sit and scribble and see what can be found on ebay, and then experiment with values to get things close. Thanks again all.

Answer (score 1):

We know dV/dt = Ic/C  and you said dt= few seconds but we don’t know allowed droop or dV.  Let’s assume that the tolerance is 10% or 0.1 * 12V or 1.2V droop.

Then for dt=3s and 6W =12V*0.5A.  = P = V * I or I=P/V

\$C=P/V * dt/ dV= \dfrac{P}{V^2*0.1}\$

So C=0.4 Farad which is pretty big but based on my assumptions

Now for a 12V source to a 470R and 3V LED @20mA you can get 10mA at 7.7V and Pavg is 10V*15mA =150’mW And Pmax is 12*20mA so for dt=1s , dV =1/3 of 12V or 4V, C =3,000 uF

Answer (score 1):

Problem sorted! I've 12V fed into the unit and put a cap/diode combination in line on the yellow (trigger) line.

Tried a few cap sizes and ended up with 330uF giving two flash sequences after the trigger power was removed - about 3 seconds worth, and now the unit is a smooth continuous cycle as it should be and not interrupted mid sequence.

Also tried a cap to power it all, but even at 6600uF there wasn't enough to keep the unit on enough to complete a sequence.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: It took three years. Is the car still running?

Comment: 3 years to do what? 18 days ago I asked the question and I'm now sorted! Trike is running perfectly, thanks very much.

Comment: Gah! US date formats! I read it as May 2014. Thanks for letting us know. Don't forget you can accept your own answer to indicate the problem is solved.